# Can a Scanner have a slice receiver?

Tags: go

The Scanner interface (https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) makes it quite easy to configure how a type is deserialized by the database/sql API from data that has been read from a database.

I've used this in various ways to handle my own types, but I just tried reading a denormalised string list into a slice of strings, e.g.

```
type Roles []string

func (rs Roles) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    ...
}
```

It's normal for the Scan receiver to be a pointer to a zero-valued instance of the type. In the case I'm trying to write, it's a slice instead.

Is this possible?

If so, how is the size of the slice determined (it isn't known until the scanner starts parsing, e.g. by splitting an input string on commas or something similar) ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but you want to define the method on `*Roles` instead. Then you can grow the slice as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered about that option - good to have it confirmed.

Comment: This being a good answer, do you want to provide it as an SO answer? (I'll do it otherwise)

Comment: I'm on my phone. Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but you want to define the method on *Roles instead. Then you can grow the slice as needed.

```
func (rs *Roles) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    ...  check not nil
    ...  split string into words
    *rs = make(RosterRoles, len(words))
    ...  range across the words
}
```

The database/sql library will be using this something like

```
var rs Roles
err := rs.Scan("abc,def")
// rs contains []string{"abc", "def"}
```

---

*Thanks to [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316/peter) for this answer.*